# Lighting not working properly in Render View

Tags: lighting

[image: ee]

I deleted the default lighting and added a new one, but it seems i can't figure out what's wrong with it. All lighting "mode" also don't work properly, even if i crank it to like 5000.

[image]

EDIT : So apparently, when i check the light data, i was using the new one i set up. The previous one that i deleted was actually still there. I select it, and it worked... a bit. It fixed the lighting problem where the shadow doesn't appear. BUT i still don't know if this is really a problem or no, because other lighting mode are still not working (not emitting any light).

[image: ee]

Comment: done it. I also removed some stuff i didn't use, so the scene collection properties is a little different. But yeah, still didn't change anything.

Comment: So I'm not sure what's the problem, the light enlights the scene, maybe rotate it a bit so that it's not zenital, also increase its Angle a bit

Comment: well, it did kind of work, but not the way i want. it doesn't matter where i moved the light, the lighting direction seems to follow the rotation. Also, the shadow only appears when i zoom in at a certain distance, and it even look so weird. what am i missing here?

Comment: the sun works this way, its location doesn't matter, contrary to the other lights. For the shadows you should precise what you mean by "weird", the quality will depends on the Sampling ratio in the Render panel, but maybe follow some basic tutorials on lights?

Comment: do you have this issue with every files or just with this one? The idea is to know if the bad setting is due to the scene or something else.

Comment: So, what about the part where the other light mode doesn't work (doesn't emit any light)? Thanks for the explanation, though.

Comment: @lemon probably only this one, since last time i followed the Donut tutorial, the lighting works fine. But i didn't remember what kind of lighting or what setting i did use on that.

Comment: also, i added an edit on the post above. I selected the "Light" and it fixed it, but like i mentioned, it doesn't fix the other lighting mode.

Comment: I don't know why @moonboots does not have the same issue, in his answer... anyway, in the shadow part of the light data, there is a "max distance" (in cascade shadow map), increase it to 500 or more.

Comment: what do you mean by "the other light mode doesn't work (doesn't emit any light)"? If you create a new light make sure that its Strength is high enough because your scene is large. If you're talking about the other viewport shadings (Solid/Material/...) you're not supposed to see the light effect (unless you enable the Scene Lights option in Material Preview mode)

Comment: @lemon actually I'm not sure to understand the problem Alex is referring to, could you please elaborate?

Comment: Welp, you right. Apparently i scaled the object HUMONGOUS. I set the strength to 5000 W and there i see it. A glimpse of light. Thanks for that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the light does enlight the scene, maybe rotate it a bit so that it's not zenital, also increase its *Angle* a bit and decrease its *Strength*:

[image]

Comment: Apparently i had both on when i took that screenshot, so what's next?

Comment: Could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I meant this kind of shadow that you don't have in the image above : https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7E2U.png (increasing max distance solves it)